# How to show file contents in recyclerview?

Tags: android, file-io, android-recyclerview

Hello I am creating an app which reads a file and its contents should be shown in recyclerview, I have done it but only first line is showing remaining lines are not showing

My file contains data as shown below

123

345

567

I have used buffered reader and input stream to read file

Here is the class for recyclerAdapter

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends 
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.Phone> {

List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;

public RecyclerAdapter(List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers) {
    this.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Phone onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.text,viewGroup,false);
    Phone phone = new Phone(view);
    return phone;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Phone phone, int i) {

    phone.textView.setText(phoneNumbers.get(i).number);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return phoneNumbers.size();
}

public class Phone extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;
    public Phone(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    }
}
```

}

Here is the code of my class

```
public class ScheduledFragment extends Fragment {
String[] strings;
RecyclerView listView;

List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;

public ScheduledFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scheduled, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    listView = view.findViewById(R.id.list);

    ReadFile();
    initialiseAdapter();



}


private void initialiseAdapter() {
    listView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    listView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(phoneNumbers);
    listView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);

}




private void ReadFile() {
    phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getActivity().getAssets().open("phone.txt");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));



        boolean hasNext = true;

        while (hasNext) {
            String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            phoneNumbers.add(new PhoneNumber(line));
            hasNext = line != null;
        }

        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //log the exception
    }
}

}


class PhoneNumber {
    String number;

    public PhoneNumber() {

    }
    public PhoneNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

I am only getting first line show in recyclerview

Expected results:

123

345

567

results I am getting:

123

Comment: Make sure your `TextView` in the holder class set with sufficiently high number for `maxLines`.

Comment: Recyclerview reuses the custom layout file for different lines or texts i think , and I did not understand your answer, could you please explain?

Comment: In your layout definition XML ensure that the text view it's not single line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to improve your while, you don't need a variable for this:

```
while (true) {
  String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
  if(line == null) {
     break;
  } else if (line.equals("")) {
     phoneNumbers.add(new PhoneNumber("\n"));
     /*I'm not sure if you really want "/n" breaks*/
  } else {
     phoneNumbers.add(new PhoneNumber(line));
  }
  Log.d("test", line);
}
```

ps: for convention use capital letters only for **Classes** not *methods* (readFile not ReadFile)